# Pyinstaller - unable to compile script to be completely standalone

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller, wxwidgets

I'm writing an application with GUI using wxPython. I have two machines with CentOS 7. The first is a build machine and the other is clean. The build machine logically has installed everything for source compilation. I want to achieve that my application will run on any CentOS 7 machine without any depencies. So, here is the problem.

Source compilation finishes fine, but when I try to run the binary on the clean machine, I get the following error on startup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "gui.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
ImportError: /tmp/_MEI6Ni7CP/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_poll_for_reply64
main returned -1
```

My spec file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/home/user/gui'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[('images/icon.png', 'images'), ('images/logo.png', 'images'), ('images/head.jpg', 'images'), ('images/step_background.png', 'images')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='gui',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True ) # Only for debug
```

Note: when I run `yum update` on the clean machine, then everything runs fine, but I want it to be completely independent on system libraries. So user shouldn't have to update or install anything. I'm looking for a way how to 'bundle' this dependency into the application itself, but I don't know which one/how.

Is there any way how to solve this?
Thank you

Edit:
Most probably this is caused by old/missing `libxcb` library, but I still have no idea how to bundle it into binary.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem lately.

Pyinstaller excludes the libxcb libraries.
Check PyInstaller/depend/dylib.py - there you will find:

> libxcb changes ABI frequently (e.g.: between Ubuntu LTS releases) and
>   is libxcb-dri changes ABI frequently (e.g.: between Ubuntu LTS
>   releases) and is usually installed as dependency of the graphics stack
>   anyway. No need to bundle it.

... or check this commit, which has not made it into pyinstaller yet:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/4a6d74a13122b763e99f97995fbbb1c6967769bb

Try to remove "r'/libxcb.so..*': 1," in PyInstaller/depend/dylib.py.